# Creating a for-loop where i identifies data by column in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to use a for-loop to create a series of summaries of GAM models of variation in capture rate of an invertebrate species using a smoothed term for day of year (DOY), and a linear predictor incorporating weather (there are many of these).  I have made a function to run and output a model summary:

```
gamlin <- function(x) {
  m <- gam(Log10E ~ s(DOY) + x, data=eggseasongam)
  return(summary(m))
}
```

I think that I want to utilize the above in a for-loop that will sequentially take as x the weather predictors in columns 4 through 173, but am struggling to do this. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

2 approaches off the top of my head could be:

```
t<-data.frame(c1=rnorm(10),c2=rnorm(10), c3=rnorm(10))
```

1- use `formula`, which allows you to provide a character string as a formula

```
> f<-function(d,x) lm(formula(paste("c1",x,sep="~")), data=d)
> f(t,"c2")

Call:
lm(formula = formula(paste("c1", x, sep = "~")), data = d)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           c2
    -0.1567      -0.4654
```

2- Alternatively feed in the column directly

```
> f2<-function(d,x) lm(c1 ~ d[,x], data=d)
> f2(t,"c2")

Call:
lm(formula = c1 ~ d[, x], data = d)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       d[, x]
    -0.1567      -0.4654
```

Once you have settled on an approach for a dynamic regression function you can put it in a for-loop

```
 for(col in 4:173) f(t,col)
```

Chances are, you want to use the results somehow, rather than just print a summary (Perhaps take the coefficients and put them in a dataframe and graph them, or something along those lines. In which case I suggest checking out `plyr` and `reshape` packages and specficially the functions `melt` and `ddply` within each

In this case you could do as follows

```
library(melt)
library(plyr)

yvar<-t[,1]
xvars<-melt(t[,-1])
> head(xvars)
  variable      value
1       c2 -0.8200263
2       c2 -1.5359220
3       c2 -0.2107913
4       c2 -0.2950263
5       c2  0.8231989
6       c2 -0.5971358

betas<-ddply(xvars, .(variable), summarize, beta=coefficients(lm(yvar ~ value))[2])
```