# Using update() function in conjunction with gam() in new mgcv package

Tags: r, function

In order to test a series of `gam` models for capture counts for each of seven sex/life-stages of a study species, I used a function that employed `update()` to iteratively substitute into the base model a sequence of predictors and produce an AIC score for each. There appears to be a problem implementing the same code with a `gam` model in the new `mgcv` package. Here is a functional, simplified subset of data to proceed.

```
repex=structure(list(Day = c(183L, 190L, 197L, 204L, 211L, 218L, 225L, 
232L, 239L, 246L, 175L, 182L), M = c(18L, 43L, 22L, 20L, 
7L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 17L), Solar = c(77L, 59L, 20L, 
55L, -3L, -44L, 13L, 58L, 8L, 6L, -28L, 12L)), .Names = c("Day", "M", "Solar"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Before I updated `mgcv` to 1.8-9, the function ran successfully in this form (note, I edited henceforth to directly reference the variables, as opposed to attaching repex):

```
MAIC<-function(x){
  m<-gam(repex$M~s(repex$Day),data=repex,family=poisson)
  m<-update(m,.~.+x)
  return(AIC(m))
}
```

I would then produce a list of AIC scores with something like this:

```
lapply(c('Solar'),function(x) MAIC(repex[ , x]))
```

After I updated R to 3.2.3 and `mgcv` to 1.8-9, I ran the above scripts as well as simply testing the function with:

```
MAIC(repex$Solar)
```

and receive this message:

```
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
```

I have been futzing around with this and have determined that, contrary to some suggestions, there isn't anything essentially problematic with the line of code `m<-update(m,.~.+x)`. I simplified the above `MAIC` function to try to locate the source of trouble, and ran it successfully with the above repex data subset with a `glm()` and `lm()` call:

```
MAIC1 <- function(x){
  m <- glm(repex$M~repex$Day,data=repex,family=poisson)
  m <- update(m,.~.+x)
  return(AIC(m))
}
MAIC1(repex$Solar)

MAIC2 <- function(x){
  m <- lm(repex$M~repex$Day,data=repex)
  m <- update(m,.~.+x)
  return(AIC(m))
}
MAIC2(repex$Solar)
```

But when I change the model to a gam, I receive the above error:

```
MAIC3 <- function(x){
  m <- gam(repex$M~s(repex$Day),data=repex)
  m <- update(m,.~.+x)
  return(AIC(m))
}
MAIC(repex$Solar)
```

This happens no matter how the base gam is constructed, unless the `update()` is omitted as follows:

```
MAIC4<-function(x){
  m<-gam(repex$M~s(repex$Day)+x,data=repex)
  return(AIC(m))
}
MAIC4(repex$Solar)
```

My `sessionInfo()` call brings:

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```

My `ls()` call brings:

```
[1] "MAIC"  "MAIC1" "MAIC2" "MAIC3" "MAIC4" "repex"
```

My `find("x")` call brings:

```
character(0)
```

Finally, I cross-checked the AIC scores of `MAIC1(repex$Solar)`, `MAIC2(repex$Solar)`, and `MAIC4(repex$Solar)`, respectively, with:

```
AIC(glm(repex$M~repex$Day+repex$Solar,data=repex,family=poisson))
AIC(lm(repex$M~repex$Day+repex$Solar,data=repex))
AIC(gam(repex$M~s(repex$Day)+repex$Solar,data=repex))
```

Hopefully this helps clear things up.

Comment: could we have a [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000) please ... ?

Comment: Sure, @BenBolker, thanks so much for looking.  I just edited the above to add an example.  I hope that it helps. And thanks for the link helping with reproducible examples.

Comment: How sure are you this worked in older versions of R? The line `m<-update(m,.~.+x)` seems suspicious since "x" doesn't appear to be a variable in the `repexample` data.frame. Do you know what that line is supposed to do? I don't see why that would have worked in any version of R.

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, it definitely worked; I've been working on this portion of a larger project on and off for some time, and that was one of the first things I had to figure out how to do, as I have to run models with many environmental and biological predictors, for seven different life stages each. I was struggling with a way to iteratively insert each predictor in turn and assess the model for a while, and someone on this board graciously helped last year [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590563/creating-a-for-loop-where-i-identifies-data-by-column-in-r)

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match either of the answers to the question you linked to. It looks like you tried to use @rawr's answer, but he had `m <- update(m, . ~ . + ...)`. If I run his answer, it still works (R 3.2.2); if i change to `m <- update(m, . ~ . + x)` i get the same error as you do above: "object 'x' not found".

Comment: That's interesting @MrFlick...it was long enough ago that I don't remember the exact process of determining why I used the "x" once rawr helped, but it truly did work with the "x" in place of the ellipsis. I verified that both for versions that output AIC and model summaries. When I do as you did, with the ellipsis in place of "x" with my posted subset data, I receive this error message: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : '...' used in an incorrect context`. To clarify, in 3.2.2 did you get an answer (i.e. an AIC score output) using the ellipsis with data I provided?

Comment: I apologize for not having met the standards of the site with the original post, and have attempted to edit it to satisfy the criteria mentioned in the "put on hold" statement. I hope that the changes I have made are sufficient, and would welcome any further criticism.

Comment: like the other commenters I'm very suspicious that this was actually working before.  This works if you specify the focal variable as a character rather than a symbol: `MAIC2 <- function(x) { m <- gam(reformulate(c("s(Day)",x),response="M"), data=repex,family=poisson); return(AIC(m)) }; MAIC2("Solar")` (use `deparse(substitute(x))` if you really want to specify `MAIC2(Solar)` ...)

Comment: PS your examples don't work for me.  I suspect you have a variable called `x` lying around in your global workspace ...

Comment: Hi @BenBolker, thank you very much for even taking the time to look at this. I admit that I am totally at a loss reading your comments.  Starting from a completely empty workspace, I run through the above code and it comes out exactly as I have written. When you say that the examples didn't work, do you mean all of them produce the error I describe?  If I have an errant `x` lying around in the workspace, I wouldn't imagine that I would get errors for gam models but not glm or lm; furthermore, when I check the AIC output from the function for glm and lm, they are correct.

Comment: @BenBolker I would be happy to send a video of my screen in RStudio showing what I'm talking about, but I don't want to presume too much in anyone's interest in my problem.  I really am not here to waste anyone's time.

Comment: I mean that the `glm`/`lm` examples don't work for me (as expected). Running `R --vanilla`, I define `repex` as shown above and run your `glm` example and get `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Solar' not found`.  My `sessionInfo()`: `R Under development (unstable) (2015-11-29 r69717) Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit) Running under: Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)` ... results of `ls()`: `[1] "MAIC"  "repex"` ... results of `find("x")`; `character(0)`.  Can you please post (edit your question to include) results of those three commands?

Comment: you changed your examples! there's a big difference between `MAIC(Solar)` and `MAIC(repex$Solar)` ... if this gets reopened, I think we can provide a better way to do this ...

Comment: @BenBolker, thanks again for your time and patience.  I had used `attach(repex)` before but neglected to mention that.  I certainly hope the post is reopened!

Answer (score 2):

`reformulate()` is a sensible way to do this:

```
repex <- data.frame(Day = c(183, 190, 197, 204, 211, 
 218, 225, 232, 239, 246, 175, 182),
   M = c(18, 43, 22, 20, 7, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17), 
  Solar = c(77, 59, 20, 55, -3, -44, 13, 58, 
     8, 6, -28, 12))

library(mgcv)
MAIC <- function(x) { 
    form <- reformulate(c("s(Day)",x),response="M")
    m <- gam(form, data=repex,family=poisson)
    return(AIC(m)) 
}
MAIC("Solar")
```

This makes it easier, e.g., to operate over a vector of column names.

If you really want to be able to use "raw" variable names (e.g. `Solar` rather than `"Solar"`, you can use `deparse(substitute())`

```
MAIC2 <- function(x) {
    xx <- deparse(substitute(x))
    form <- reformulate(c("s(Day)",xx),response="M")
    m <- gam(form, data=repex,family=poisson)
    return(AIC(m)) 
}
MAIC2(Solar)
```

(alternatively, you could just write `MAIC2 <- function(x) MAIC(deparse(substitute(x)))` ...)

If you *really* want to use `update` with raw variables it takes a little more magic ...

```
MAIC3 <- function(x) {
   m <- gam(M~s(Day),data=repex,family=poisson)
   m2 <- update(m,bquote(.~.+.(substitute(x))))
   return(AIC(m2))
}
MAIC3(Solar)
```